# Keep parent hover state on navigation whilst in submenu

Tags: jquery, css

I'm writing a navigation and im just wondering if its possible to keep the hover state on a parent link with css?

When you hover into my subnav the parent link :hover style dissapears...

http://jsfiddle.net/mSNqT/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the :hover on the li instead of the a.  I updated your jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mSNqT/1/

Answer (score 1):

Move the `dropdown` class from the `a` to its parent `li`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mSNqT/2/)

Answer (score 0):

In your menu are no visible hover styles at all that could disappear.

Comment: Yes there is. It adds a `background-image`.

Comment: But that background image is also there when you hover into the subnav. I use FF. With what browser do you have that problem?